# Get Username from UID with Preprocess for Template

Tags: 8, users

I'm a bit lost at finding the username based on the uid. I get the uid from the address using:

```
  $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
  $urluid = (explode("/",$current_path));

  $us = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user')
  ->loadByProperties(['uid' => $urluid[2]]);

  kint($us);
```

returns an array of data where i do see the uid, but not the username for that uid. Name:

```
'name' => array(1)
*DEPTH TOO GREAT*
```

returns NULL:

```
kint($us->name);
```

I'd like to return the UID->Name as the title on the ROLES and EDIT screens for the user. Exactly how it is returned for VIEW (example dvweb is: /user/10):
[image: d]

EDIT:::

Was able to get it with:

```
  $u = Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($urluid[2]);
    kint($u->getUsername());
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use the route instead of the path, where you'll find the already loaded user entity:

```
if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'entity.user.canonical') {
  $user = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('user');
  $username = $user->getUsername();
}
```

Comment: I'll give this a try!